# Authors being omitted in certain bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies

From the following bib entries, the authors are being omitted.  Help, need to submit soon!

```
@article{Fu_2010,
authors = "Xiao, T. F. and Sang, M. K.",
title = "Agarase: Review of Major Sources, Categories, Purification Method, Enzyme Characteristics and Applications",
journal = "Marine Drugs",
volume = "8",
year = "2010",
pages = "200--218"
}

@article{Lee_etal2006,
authors = "Lee, D.-G. and Park, G.-T. and Kim, N. Y. and Lee, E.-J. and Jang, M. K. and Shin, Y. G. and Park, G.-S. and Kim, T.-M. and Lee, J.-H. and Lee, J.-H. and Kim, S.-J. and Lee, S.-H.",
title = "Cloning, expression, and characterization of a glycoside hydrolase family 50 b-agarase from a marine Agarivorans isolate",
journal = "Biotechnology Letters",
volume = "28",
issue = "23",
year = "2006",
pages = "1925--1932"
}
```

Comment: -1 for "urgent priority".

Comment: Well, it was a genuine urgency.  I hoped you could sympathise, we all have these moments, realising something is wrong only after careful inspection in the last hours leading up to a deadline.  I don't apologise for it.

Comment: Sure, but asking for quick answers does not really help.

Comment: I've removed the "urgent" label from the title now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The BibTeX entry should read `author`, not `authors`!